# Task assignment with constraints in combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can you assign $\eta$ different integer tasks $\left(\eta<\infty\right)$ to $k$ employees $\left(k<\eta\right)$
>   if the toughest task must belong to your best employee, whilst the simplest task shall be executed by the only 2016 newcomer of your firm?

That question, I can't seem to legitimately figure a way out. So that any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Without the restriction, you can assign each task in $k$ ways.  The restriction forces two of the tasks to be assigned in particular ways, so you only have $\eta-2$ tasks left to assign.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , so following Mr. Millikan's hint I figure this out:

Once the assigments of the hardest and easiest job have been made, there are $\:\eta-2\:\:$different jobs to assign to $\:k\:\:$different employees.

Thus, we are looking for the number of functions from a set of$\:\:\eta-2\:\:$elements to a set with $k\:$elements, wich yields $\:k^{\:\eta-2}$ such functions.

$\\$

Now, on a more realistic note, if we impose the restriction that every employee must accept at least one job, then we're constraint to dismiss all the assignments in wich the jobs go only to each the most skilled and the newcomer employees.

In the same way of thought as the first part of this question, we see that there are $\:2\:^{\eta-2}\:$such assignments. So, in this case, the number of ways to distribute those jobs shall be $\:k^{\:\eta-2}-2^{\:\eta-2}$

Comment: Yes, $k^{\eta-2}$ is correct.  In the followup, $2^{\eta-2}$ is the number of ways to assign all the tasks just to the most senior and most junior employees.  Subtracting those does not guarantee that every employee gets at least one task, it just guarantees that at least one other employee gets at least one task.

Comment: Computing the number of ways to assign the tasks so that each employee gets at least one is somewhat more complicated. In the rest here, I will ignore the restriction on the hardest and easiest tasks.  There are a total of $k^\eta$ ways to assign the tasks.  The number of ways to assign them to $k-1$ employees would seem to be $k$ (ways to select the unused employee) times $(k-1)^\eta$ (ways to assign the tasks) so you would subtract that.  Unfortunately, you have double counted the ways to leave two people without a task, so you have to add those back in.

Comment: The way to account for this is the inclusion-exclusion principle. It comes up often on this site, and you can read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) on it.

Comment: Ok thanks, great advice.